# Limit the size of a member collection in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have a problem because I don't know if it is possible to limit the size of the activities list.

I wish to only retrieve  most recent 5 activities. Is it possible to automatically do it during any fetch from DB? (so that I don't have to limit the collection by hand in Java).

```
@Entity
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @OrderBy("timestamp DESC")
    @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private List<Activity> activities;


    // other setters, getters, etc. 
}
```

Essentially I'd like to keep, say, 20 entries in the ACTIVITY entries (dropping the oldest rows, when newer are inserted), but fetch only 5 latest.

Is this possible?